# Can I visit external urls with turbo native without opening external browser?

Tags: turbo, hotwire

I have a web application that uses turbo and now I want to create a web application using turbo native. However, I need to do some redirecting to external urls for identification and it won’t work if the external urls are opened in an external web browser.

My web application uses tulo payway for logins and use their single sign on (SSO). There is an image describing the setup here: [SSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUBjr.png)

So basically what I want is to embed the website [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) with turbo native. However, for the login process to work, I also need the app to access the external urls for:

- [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)
- PW-SSO

The urls above are not using turbo so it would be a break from “the turbo way”.

This works nicely on the web. It also works if I only create a simple android app with a web view that I set to point to the xyz url.

Is there a way to fix this so that the turbo native app can work with external urls without opening the urls in a new browser?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution or a workaround?

Comment: Nope, I haven't find anything that solves the problem with turbo native. However, if one uses tulo, one can use mobile login to get an access token from the native app and then pass that token to get an authorization ticket which can be used on a different landing page. That way the user will never leave the main doman www.xyz.com.

That bypasses the restrictions by turbo native but it doesn't really solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I check for the sso host and then instead of navigating I load the url directly in the WebView. E.g. for android in the shouldNavigateTo()

```
session.webview.loadUrl(URL)
return false
```

and for ios in the route() function

```
session.webView.load(URL)
return // cancel the function
```

I don't know if this is the best practice but it works for me.